# Touch event on Alexa Show not forwarded to skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

One of my Alexa skill responses contains a Display Directive for the BodyTemplate1.

I noticed that if the screen is touched then the speech is immediately stopped. Not too much of a problem in itself but what is a problem is that,  if I don't say anything after touching the screen, then eventually the skill closes BUT my skill doesn't receive a SessionEndedRequest.

I am manually storing state between sessions so I need the SessionEndedRequest to clean up my storage tables.

Does anyone know anything about this behavior?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail as to the architecture of your application? Is it a quiz app etc. etc.